# Are Z-score and t-score comparable?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, z-score

I have a computational model parameterized with a single integral value, say $p$ valid for a relatively small range (< 100).

Values returned by the model are normally distributed (or at least approximately) with mean $μ_p$ and standard deviation $σ_p$, except for a special value of $p$ (say $p_{sp}$), for which the values returned have mean $μ_{p_{sp}}$ and $σ_{p_{sp}}$. I don't know $μ_p$, $σ_p$, $μ_{p_{sp}}$, or $σ_{p_{sp}}$.

My goal is to find $p_{sp}$, that is, the value for which there is a separate distribution.

I can generate samples, but generating samples is expensive. Computing statistics is effectively free.

I think there are 2 tests that can help here:

1. Z-score - effective for detecting outliers (valid for a single sample)
2. T-score - effective for hypothesis testing (valid for two populations with few samples)

Because sampling is so expensive, I need to make decisions about where to sample next. That is, is it better to sample other values of $p$ or sample more of a particular value $p'$ that looks promising.

Since computing statistics is cheap, I can calculate Z-scores for each data point and run T-value for every pair of distributions (that is $p'$ and not $p'$).

Is there a way to numerically compare a Z-score and T-score to decide to decide which is least likely?

That is, if there is a high Z-score (e.g. > 2.5), that's a good place to sample more; if there is a high t-score, that's a good place to sample more. There will always be a maximum Z-score and t-score. (There might be neither, in which case you choose to sample using some other criteria.)

*Disclaimer - this question IS derived from coursework for computer-based timing attacks. My interest is whether there is a mathematically rigorous approach to this type of problem.*

Comment: This sounds ripe for mixture modeling.  Take a look here:  https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/intro_to_mixture_models.html or here
http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch20.pdf